# How to hide unused placeholders/folders Eclipse RCP/RAP

Tags: eclipse-rcp, perspective, eclipse-rap

I am struggling to have only two views stacked, to have them only in one window, no other placeholder/folder shown.

My perspective looks like:

```java
public class PerspectiveNew implements IPerspectiveFactory {
  public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    IFolderLayout folderLayout = layout.createFolder("folder", IPageLayout.TOP, 1.0F, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
    folderLayout.addView(MyView1.ID);
    folderLayout.addView(MyView2.ID);
  }
}
```

When I open my RCP app I am still seeing bottom placeholder. How to get rid off that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public class PerspectiveNew implements IPerspectiveFactory {
  public void createInitialLayout(IPageLayout layout) {
    IFolderLayout folderLayout = layout.createFolder("folder", IPageLayout.TOP, 1.0F, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
    folderLayout.addView(MyView1.ID);
    folderLayout.addView(MyView2.ID);
    layout.setEditorAreaVisible(false); // Turn-off visibility of other placeholders/folders
  }
}
```